# INJOINIC IP5209T Charging Circuit Troubleshooting

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, i2c, boost, esp32

I have put together a PCB design that uses an INJOINIC IP5209T charging IC as a 3.7V LiPo charger and 5V boost output. I have assembled the PCB but it does not seem to be working properly.

### Problem 1

If I press the power button once when the battery is connected, the IP5209T does not supply power to the rest of the circuit. If I hold the power button for 2 seconds, the LED power indicator comes on (as expected per the datasheet). I double press the power button and the LED power indicator turns off. If I connect USB power to the VIN of the IP5209T, it DOES supply power to the rest of the circuit. This is expected.

### Problem 2

When the IP5209T is supplying power to the rest of the circuit, it is powering an ESP32. I have firmware on the ESP32 scanning for devices connected to the I2C bus. The IP5209T datasheet advertises it is I2C capable on pins L1 and L2. These pins are connected to the ESP32 as shown in the schematic, but the firmware shows no I2C devices are available for communication.

The issue must be hardware related but I am not sure what that issue could be. This is my first time designing anything using the IP5209T. If anyone knows how this IC works or has any suggestions, please feel free to comment.

#### Here is my charging circuit

External power can be provided to the IP5209T via 5V USB (VCC_IN). Battery power is supplied via a 3.7V LiPo using a JST connector (BAT). 5V output from the IP5209T (VCC_OUT) goes to a 3.3V regulator to supply power to the ESP32.
[image]

Comment: I2C cannot work with 2.2K resistors in series (and no pull up resistors, but maybe these are internal pull-ups in one of the chips?)

Comment: The typical application schematic in the datasheet differs greatly from yours regarding how the battery voltage- and current sensing is connected, are you sure yours is correct?

Comment: @Unimportant I the 2.2k resistors on SDA and SCL for the IP5306 I2C. I assumed it would function the same (I could be wrong of course).

As for the typical application schematic, I am not 100% sure my schematic is correct. I was hoping to find out what I could do to correct it

Comment: @jsotola The `problem 1`: I have documented the actual behavior but neglected to mention the expected behavior.

Expected behavior: With only the battery connected and no USB, a single press of the KEY button should result in the IP5209T supplying 5V power to the rest of the circuit. A double press should result in the IP5209T shutting down the power to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: The device can't pull the bus lines low from behind those 2.2K resistances, so how is it supposed to communicate?

Comment: @the.red.team have you ever fixed the problem 1? I have exact same issue